# Как передать переменную в layouts/main.php

Tags: yii2

Есть `SiteController` в нем функция

```
   public function index(){
    $contactForm = new FooterForm();
    if ($contactForm->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $contactForm->validate()) {
        if ($contactForm->sendEmail()) {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Спасибо - мы свяжемся с Вами в ближайшее время');
        } else {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', 'Произошла ошибка при отправке сообщения.');
        }

        return $this->refresh();
    }
    return [
        'contactForm' => $contactForm,
    ];
}
```

Если в `main.php` `var_dump($contactForm);`, то получается ошибка

> Undefined variable: contactForm
>   public_html/plitka/engine/frontend/themes/magichotel/views/layouts/main.php
>   176

Comment: Так вы через рендер передайте.
return $this->render('viewname', ['contactForm' => $contactForm]);

Comment: Не получается, попробовал, результат тот же

Comment: У вас логика не совсем верная. Можете создать модель contactForm, подключить её в layout/main => use ContactForm; и рисовать там же. Посмотрите как реализована форма авторизации loginForm из стандартной сборки. Но такая вещь нужна для глобальной верстки. Можете перенести вашу логику в новый экшн типа "actionFeedback()" и в нём вызывать форму отправики.

Answer (score 1):

Можно передать в глобальный массив `Yii::$app->params['form'] = $contactFrom;`
после этого в layouts/main.php оно будет доступно как `Yii::$app->params['form']`

Comment: А где передавать в глобальный массив? В контроллере или где?

Comment: В любом месте можно, например да, в контроллере